# How to convert rails app to test files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, reverse-engineering, rspec-rails

I like to create rspec test from working rails 5 app.
It' could be template to work on.

For example: 
-scaffold will create test files template which is nice.
-Or [simplecov](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov) to help increase test ratio (if I understand correctly)
-So if any tools that could run through each line of controller method and re-create each expected/result put in the test file.

Are there any gem or solution ?

Why ask this question?.
I understand this is not a purpose of test. However test is to save time in future and now as well. Many rails app don't have test, and to go back each line of running code will cost again, assuming the app is good at this stage. If we can have all test at this point and use it to control / run for future development that would be good

Comment: I don't think there are any tools like that, you need to write tests by yourself, even if there are any tool to read the files/methods and create spec files for you, it'd just be bare bones spec files, you'd have to write the expected cases yourself

Comment: there is...... https://github.com/Nedomas/zapata. but I'm not sure if it's any good or is compatible with your solution.

Comment: It's look right what I asked for. I will need to try with previous ruby and rails. Will update later. Thk

Comment: @Josh Brody, I tried zapata but no luck to make it work with my ruby or rails. I can not use ruby lower than 2.4 or rails 4. Their parser required lower ruby (2.1+) and rails 3.0+

Comment: @t.kul it's not a terribly hard thing to write yourself. you'll just be doing a lot of `MyController.instance_methods(false)` and looping through. Similarly, `Model.instance_methods(false),` `Model.methods(false)` — that codebase should get you on the right track too.

Answer (score 0):

I found another gem that answer my question 
[rspec-kickstarter](https://github.com/seratch/rspec-kickstarter)
But to use with Rails 5 it need to edit the path that created.